# how to store every element of api response list to a List<String> in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have to Store Every Element of List to List so how i can do this?

Json Response as below.

```
{
  "responseCode": 200,
  "responseMessage": "OK",
  "data": null,
  "dataList": [
    "Technical",
    "Field"
  ],
  "excelDataList": null,
  "totalRecords": 2,
  "pageRecords": 0,
  "currentPageNumber": 1,
  "totalPages": 0
}
```

Here i have to store dataList values in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to call `jsonDecode` to convert your String into deserialized data, then you can use the `[]` operator to access individual keys.

[Read more at](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json)

```
import "dart:convert";

const String apiResult = """{
  "responseCode": 200,
  "responseMessage": "OK",
  "data": null,
  "dataList": [
    "Technical",
    "Field"
  ],
  "excelDataList": null,
  "totalRecords": 2,
  "pageRecords": 0,
  "currentPageNumber": 1,
  "totalPages": 0
}
""";

void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> des = jsonDecode(apiResult);
  List<dynamic> data = des["dataList"];
  
  print(data);
}
```

which would print

```
> [Technical, Field]
```